# Matlab Evaluation with Symbolic Matrices

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

```
syms a b;

T = sym('T',[1 5]);

z = a + b + T(1) + T(2);

a = 3;
```

I want the answer as `3+b+T1+T2`, but `eval(z)` is not working. What can I do?

Comment: `subs(z,a,3)` might work to substitute `a` in the expression `z` with `3`?

Comment: No, it gives me T1 + T2 + a + b

Comment: Don't use `eval`.  Use `subs` as what mikkola suggested.  In addition, remove the `a = 3` statement.

Comment: It is not working @rayryeng

Comment: @Kamil It's working for me. https://codeshare.io/8vpyh

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your edit. It works thank you @rayryeng

Comment: @Kamil No problem. I've written an answer.  Please consider accepting the answer if you no longer need help.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `eval`. Use [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) as what mikkola suggested. In addition, remove the `a = 3` statement.

```
>> syms a b;
>> T = sym('T',[1 5]);
>> z = a + b + T(1) + T(2);
>> subs(z,a,3)

ans =

    T1 + T2 + b + 3
```

Comment: Just to add a bit more: The reason that `sym/eval` does not work is that only the symbolic matrix `T`, not its named elements, have been explicitly added to the workspace (type `syms` by itself to view to list symbolic objects in the workspace). There is usually nothing wrong with using `sym/eval` in the manner the OP is trying (don't confuse it with `eval`), but provided that a symbolic variable is in the workspace.